# Change a subdomain/domain?

Tags: php, regex, filter

I'm working on a project to rip google.docs videos out as redirectors in php and put them in a videojs player (since doc's current player is in flash)

What I have so far works good but it rips links out like so

https://r8---sn-vgqs7n7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=a8fa0f1624209c52&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=2604:5800:0:35:250:56ff:fe9e:85f5&ipbits=32

I want to use PHP to replace the entire domain/sub-domain with https:redirector.googlevideo.com/ but keep everything after it like this

https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=a8fa0f1624209c52&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=2604:5800:0:35:250:56ff:fe9e:85f5&ipbits=32

I'm currently using the following line to replace unicode from the link already, but I have no idea how to go about replacing the first domain line. Any ideas?

$links = str_replace(array('\u003d', '\u0026'), array('=', '&'), $cat[1]);

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), this will replace the part of string that is between https:// and the first slash :

```
$link = 'https://r8---sn-vgqs7n7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=a8fa0f1624209c52&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=2604:5800:0:35:250:56ff:fe9e:85f5&ipbits=32';

$link = preg_replace('#https://[^/]+#', 'https://redirector.googlevideo.com', $link);
echo $link;
```

**Output:**

```
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=a8fa0f1624209c52&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=2604:5800:0:35:250:56ff:fe9e:85f5&ipbits=32
```

**Explanation:**

```
#           : regex delimiter
  https://  : literally https://
  [^/]+     : one or more character that is not a slash
#           : regex delimiter
```